# Problema de personalización

Tags: java, android-studio, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Trabajo en un proyecto que trata sobre una aplicación de tareas, actualmente estoy usando esta dependencia para la vista del calendario.

[Esta es la dependencia que uso]
https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

EL problema radica en que en la documentación de la dependencia no encuentro o no veo la manera de poder cambiar los colores de las fecha y los títulos del calendario de forma personalizada. Sería de ayuda que me explicaran una forma o método de poder solucionar esto, si es que se puede.